# Security error in ASP NET shared account

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, .net-3.5

These lines cause a security exception in a godaddy account. Any suggestions how to rewrite to get this to work?

```
File.Delete(PropsFileName);     // Clean up

TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(PropsFileName);    // Create & open the file
tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);     // Write the date for reference
tw.WriteLine(TokenLine);        // Write the BinarySecurityToken
tw.WriteLine(ConvIdLine);       // Write the ConversationId
tw.WriteLine(ipccLine);     // Write the IPCC
tw.Close();
```

Thanks!

The information is being written to session.properties variable in the temp directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GoDaddy is set up to run under Medium trust, to simulate this on localhost add the following to your web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <trust level="Medium" />
</system.web>
```

Something you can try to fix the issues is to add the following to your AssemblyInfo.cs under Project > Properties in solution explorer

```
[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]
```

Also here is an article that may or may not help you out and/or give you insight regarding a similar situation with NHibernate: [NHibernate in a Medium Trust Environment](http://www.gavaghan.org/blog/2007/08/21/nhibernate-in-a-medium-trust-environment/)

Answer (score 0):

You should give NTFS permissions to the user running your ASP.NET app. Your hosting control panel probably supports assigning NTFS permissions to the folder.